# Cmder Here always opens in default directory

Tags: cmd.exe, conemu, cmder

I registered Cmder to be able to right click on my folders and do "Cmder here" but it's always opening in the default user directory, how can I fix this?

Comment: Cmder changes directory in its init.cmd

Answer (score 5):

This answer is inspired by kjeske's response in [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/203):

Go to `Cmder` settings, `Startup` --> `Tasks`, and select `{cmd:Cmder}` as shown below:

[image: Cmder settings]

Make sure the `new_console` parameter is set to `%__CD__%`.

Do the same for other `Tasks` (such as `{cmd:Cmder as Admin}`), if you use them.

Comment: For version `191012 preview` we must use `%CD%` instead `%__CD__%`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and press the right mouse button <kbd>RMB</kbd> in a directory?

If it's set as the default shell it will pop up instead of the Command Prompt when the option `Open command window here` is clicked

[image]

I also suggest radically switching to [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/)

Comment: cmder uses ConEmu, so it's really not an issue. I also know about the right click and since I registered Cmder as default, it does work, but it also creates a new ontry in the menu so you don't have to shift + right click, that's the one that doesn't work